# Different values of the numeric integral evaluated by using different methods

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

Consider the space of three variables $x,y,z$ defined in the ranges
$$
\tag 1 x \in (0,\pi), \quad y \in (0,\pi), \quad z\in (0,2\pi),
$$
and the following `UnitStep` "projector":

```
Cosα[x_, y_, z_] = Cos[z]*Sin[x]*Sin[y] + Cos[x]*Cos[y];
E1crit[m1_, m2_] = (m1^2 + m2^2)/(2*m2);
Cosαcrit[E1_, m1_, m2_] = 
  If[E1 < E1crit[m1, m2], -1, 
   1/(2*m2) Sqrt[4 E1^2 m2^2 - m2^4 - 2 m2^2 m1^2 - m1^4]/Sqrt[
    E1^2 - m1^2]];
Projector[E1_, m1_, m2_, x_, y_, z_] = 
  UnitStep[Cosα[x, y, z] - Cosαcrit[E1, m1, m2]];
```

Here $E_{1},m_{1},m_{2}$ are parameters. It turns out that for values $E_{1}<E_{1\text{ crit}}$ the projector is simply identity for the whole domain $(1)$.

Now I define the integrals of some function `function` with the projector evaluated above using two different evaluation methods (using `UnitStep` and using `ImplicitRegion`):

```
M2=6.3;

IntegratedProjector1[E1_, m1_, function_, method_] := 
 NIntegrate[
      function*Projector[E1, m1, M2, x, y, z], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, {z,
        0, 2*Pi}, Method -> method]
RegionOfIntegration[E1_, m1_, m2_] := 
 ImplicitRegion[
  Cosα[x, y, z] - Cosαcrit[E1, m1, m2] > 
   0, {{x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}}]
IntegratedProjector2[E1_, m1_, function_, method_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  function, {x, y, z} ∈ RegionOfIntegration[E1, m1, M2], 
  Method -> method]
```

I have two questions

**1)** Let's compare the values of `IntegratedProjector1` and `IntegrationProjector2` for unit function, `QuasiMonteCarlo` method and particular values of $E_{1},m_{1}$:

```
IntegratedProjector1[0.5*E1crit[2, M2], 2, 1, QuasiMonteCarlo]
IntegratedProjector2[0.5*E1crit[2, M2], 2, 1, QuasiMonteCarlo]
```

The first integral gives reasonable value, while the second evaluates to 0. If I, however, change the method to Automatic in the second integral, it gives similar values for $E_{1} < E_{1\text{ crit}}$. What can be a reason for this?

**2)** For $E_{1}\gg E_{1\text{ crit}}$ the first integral gives zero for `Automatic` method and non-zero for `QuasiMonteCarlo`, while the second integral gives zero for `QuasiMonteCarlo` and not zero for `Automatic`:

```
IntegratedProjector1[50*E1crit[2, M2], 2, 1, Automatic]
IntegratedProjector2[50*E1crit[2, M2], 2, 1, Automatic]
```

What can be a reason for this?

Comment: In the first case, it is clear that this is just the volume  $2\pi ^3=62.0126$. What is expected in the second case?

Comment: @AlexTrounev : it is expected to be small, but non-zero, since for large $E_{1}$ the value of $\cos(\alpha_{\text{crit}})$ tends to unit value, and only small amount of volume is remained.

Comment: Are you sure this is a volume, not a surface? It seems that the solution to inequality is a 2D domain, not a 3D one.

Comment: @AlexTrounev : it think that it is volume since the UnitStep leaves the domain $\cos(\alpha(x,y,z))>\cos(\alpha_{\text{crit}})$ (which determines a volume), not the domain with equality (which would determine a surface).

Comment: It is easy to check. Build  `RegionPlot3D[RegionOfIntegration[0.5*E1crit[2, M2], 2, M2],  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev : for $E_{1}>E_{1\text{ crit}}$ it is a volume which is shrinked to a something like a rectangle with frameworks with growth of $E_{1}$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev : please take a look on it:
https://imgur.com/a/gqGwB7N